# C++11: what is the proper way to migrate from old-style enum to enum class?

Tags: c++, casting, c++11, enums

I am currently migrating my code from the old-style enum to enum class.

The strong-typing is nice, but I came across a point in the code where I needed to call ncurses's init_pair() function which takes a `short int` as its first argument, but which I have converted to an enum class for developer-friendly reading.

To make the compiler happy, it seems that I need to use a `static_cast<short int>()` on the first parameter.

Is there a cleaner approach or if I must use the static_cast, how do you recommend that I use it?

**Accepted Answer**:  Chris Dodd's answer is good.  Before the switch, I had ints all over the place representing the old-style enums.  After the switch, I have one dirty cast with type-safe enums all over the rest of the code.  The dirtiness is isolated to one spot, the code is safer, and it's easier to read.  This is a marked improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to define an overloaded inline version of init_pair that takes an enum and casts it to call the normal version:

```
inline int init_pair(enum_type pair, short f, short b) {
    return init_pair(static_cast<short>(pair), f, b);
}
```

That way users can call it with you enum type and it will just work

Comment: good idea - at least the dirtiness is isolated to one spot - I will wrap the external call

Comment: As a note, `short(pair)` and `(short)pair` will work equally well if you just want to avoid ugliness; on the other hand, static_cast does have the advantage of being easy to search for, unlike the C-style and function-style casts!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a cleaner way to do this or is the static_cast ok?

Cleaner? You're doing something unclean: taking a strongly-typed value and changing it to another type. You're deliberately circumventing the type system. When you do something unclean, it should look unclean.

The only "cleaner" way to do it is with a C-style cast. And I'm not sure that this is "cleaner".

Comment: unfortunately, init_pair() is an external library call so I can't modify that interface

Comment: Chris Dodd's suggestion is right - isolate the dirty code into one spot and strictly use the enum_type throughout the code-base.